# How do I Find bindingSource by Name?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have many bindingsource in my winform, and I wanna change my gridview's dataSource dynamically，so I wanna Get bindingSource by there's name.
I have find following code to find all bindingSource from my winform,

the name mean's bindingSource name property 
In the picture ,it's name is "bsSL070101"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Q4t.png)

```
    private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
    {
        return from field in GetType().GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               where typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
               let component = (Component)field.GetValue(this)
               where component != null
               where component.ToString().Contains("Windows.Forms.BindingSource")
               select component;
    }
```

After I got my BindingSourceList I wanna filter one of them by name, But I don't know how to do,please help me, thanks~

```
    IEnumerable<Component> BindingSourceList = EnumerateComponents();
    //I wonder find a bindingSource by name, but it doesn't work
    BindingSource bb = BindingSourceList.find(a=>a.name=="bsSL070101");
```

Comment: Component have name just at design-time. If at run-time you need to find them using their name, you need to rely on field name.

Comment: One of the many stupid things about c#. I still dont understand why components dont have a name property at runtime. The only reason I can think of is to make life of a debugger more hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component have name just at design-time. If at run-time you need to find them using their name, you need to rely on field name.

The following piece of code returns all fields of the form in a `Dictionary<string, BindingSource>`:

```
var bindingSources = this.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(x => typeof(BindingSource).IsAssignableFrom(x.FieldType))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (BindingSource)x.GetValue(this));
```

You can find your binding source by name in the dictionary:

```
var bs = bindingSources["categoriesBindingSource"];
```

Note:

- If the name is not important and you need just instances which you have added using designer:

  ```
  var bindingSources = this.components.Components.OfType<BindingSource>();
  ```

Comment: Amazing~
It' totally work!!
That's what exactly I want , thank you very much!!
Without your help, I couldn’t have done it.